# How to install/manage Apache on Windows Server without GUI

Tags: windows, apache, cygwin, wamp

I am trying to figure out what's the best way to install/manage an Apache Webserver on Windows. **I can't access the GUI, the only thing I can access is `CYGWIN` over `SSH`**.

So the Question is how to do this?

- Is there a Way to run the `WAMP` Installer from the Commandline?
- Or would you recommend me going with the `CYGWIN` Pakage?
- Are there any alternatives to these two approaches?

Edit: I know about the [Apache Docs on Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html), but they are really poor if you ask me.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Use a precompiled CygWin package, install it this way:

   ```
   wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
   install apt-cyg /bin
   apt-cyg install apache
   ```
2. Compile and install apache on Cygwin yourself, as shown here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/win_compiling.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have good experience with Apache on CygWin? Do you have documentation on how to manage the apache on cygwin? Are there methods like apachectl?

Comment: There is the usual /usr/sbin/apachectl2 for controllig it. Actually since CygWin simulates a normal linux system, there are all the usual ways of configuring and using all the tools. I do not have deeper experiences running apache under CygWin. I assume from the performance point of view it will behave much like under linux except for the fact that process creation / forking takes other resources and has other impact on cpu than under linux.